# How to get the login token in signin with Google ?

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, swift2, google-calendar-api

In my App. I want to login with Google account any sync his calendar with my app. When I login with google SDK I see the some kind of token like below Image. but I don't know how to take this.

[image]

I have used the below code to login.

```
@IBAction func btnGoogleClicked(){

    self.presentViewController(self.createAuthController(), animated: true) { 
        self.hideAddAccountView();
    }
}


//MARK: -  Google calendar Method 

func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch{
    let authController : GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch;
    let arrScopes = NSMutableArray();

    arrScopes.addObject(kGTLAuthScopeCalendarReadonly)
    arrScopes.addObject("profile")

    authController = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: arrScopes.componentsJoinedByString(" "), clientID: kClientID, clientSecret: nil, keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: #selector(HomeVC.viewController(_:auth:error:)))
    authController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = true
    return authController;
}

func viewController(vc : GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch, auth : GTMOAuth2Authentication,error : NSError?){

    if (error != nil) {
        AlertView.showOKTitleMessageAlert("Authentication Error", strMessage: error!.localizedDescription, viewcontroller: self)
        self.service.authorizer = nil;
    }
    else {

        self.service.authorizer = auth;

        print("email  - \(auth.userEmail)")
        print("userDate  - \(auth.userData)")
        print("properties = \(auth.properties)")
        print("properties = \(vc.signIn.userProfile)")
        print("properties = \(vc.signIn.userData)")
        currentLoginDictionary = vc.signIn.userProfile

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        fatchEvents()

    }
}


func fatchEvents(){

    let query = GTLQueryCalendar.queryForEventsListWithCalendarId("primary")

    query.maxResults = 150;
    query.timeMin = GTLDateTime.init(date: NSDate(), timeZone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())
    query.singleEvents = true;
    query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

    self.service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinishSelector: #selector(HomeVC.eventFatchedSuccessfully(_:events:error:)))

}

func eventFatchedSuccessfully(ticket : GTLServiceTicket,events : GTLCalendarEvents,error : NSError?){

    print("ticket \(ticket.userData) \(ticket.APIKey)")
}
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Have you checked the [Calendar API for Swift](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) ?

Comment: Yes i have check this api already. My exact problem is I want to login with multiple google account in my app and sync calendar event of all account.